# Questions about harmonic functions (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I was studying harmonic functions and had some confusions. A theorem was introduced which is: If $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is analytic, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions. The proof was done by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So, if $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, they are harmonic. Is the converse true? If $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions, do they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Another confusion is the conjugate harmonic function. If we have $u(x,y)$ which is harmonic, and if we can find a harmonic function $v(x,y)$ such that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then $v$ is the conjugate harmonic function of $u$. Is the converse also true? If $v$ is the conjugate harmonic of $u$, do $v$ and $u$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Is it also true that if $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ is harmonic, then f(z) = $u(x,y)$ + $iv(x,y)$ is analytic? I know that if $u$ and $v$ are conjugate harmonic of each other, then $f(z)$ is analytic. But what if they aren't? And IF $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are harmonic conjugates of each other, how do we decide which one of $u$ and $v$ gets to be the imaginary function of $f(z)$ if $f(z)$ is analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is real harmonic function on the entire complex plane then there is always  a harmonic conjugate $v$ but $v$ is only unique up to a  constant. $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$ if and only if $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ if and only if $u+iv$ is analytic.  It is impossible for $u$ and $v$ to be harmonic conjugates of each other except when they are both constants.

Comment: So v is a harmonic conjugate of u iff the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold iff u + iv is analytic? I know that if u + iv is analytic, then u and v satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold but the converse isn't true, is it?

Comment: The converse is also true.

Comment: So v is harmonic conjugate of u iff u and v satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations? Also u  and v satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations iff u + iv is analytic? Sorry if I'm repeating but I need this confusion cleared. Thank you

Comment: @SonnyJordan Both are correct but differentiability **at point** is not equivalent to C-R equations. As long as you are discussing analyticity in an open set the three statements are equivalent.